# Is $\det (A + B)=\det (A) + \det (B) + \operatorname{tr}(A \operatorname{adj}(B))$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A,B \in {M_n}$.

Is this true that $\det (A + B) = \det (A) + \det (B) + \operatorname{tr}(A\operatorname{adj}(B))$?

Comment: No, the simplest counter-example is $A = B = I_n$ for $n > 2$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please always include some English words in the question title, so that on right-click, the browser's context menu is not overridden by the MathJax menu.

Comment: This is always true when $n=2$, but as another user has pointed out, it's not necessarily true for larger $n$s.

Answer (score 3):

- $n=2$, $\newcommand{\tr}{\operatorname tr}$ $$\det(A+B) = \det(A) + \det(B) + \tr(A) \tr(B) - \tr(AB).$$
- $n=3$, letting $c(X) = (tr(X)^2 – tr(X^2)) / 2$, $$det(A + B) = det(A) + det(B) – tr(AB)tr(A) – tr(AB)tr(B) \\+ c(A)tr(B) + tr(A)c(B)\\ + tr(AAB) + tr(ABB)$$
- $n>3$, a formula with  $2^n$ terms should be obtainable from the [1987 Reutenauer and Schützenberger's "A formula for the determinant of a sum of matrices"](http://igm.univ-mlv.fr/~berstel/Mps/Travaux/A/1987-2FormulaDeterminantMathPhys.pdf)

Comment: How do prove this formula?

Comment: For $A = B = I we get 2^n = 1 + 1 + n^2 - n$, which is incorrect in general.

Comment: @H.S,Andreas, thanks for catching this, I've revised my answer.